# Левелап хеллоуворлдщика

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток. Почитал несколько книжек по чистому C++. Прошло уже достаточно времени и стадию хеллоу ворлдов я давно прошел. Захотелось чего-нибудь более практического, прочитал книгу Айвора Хортона по программированию под винду. Теперь же хочется поднять свой скилл, набраться опыта. Что бы мне такого написать, для этих целей? Думал написать простейшую качалку файлов, но пока даже не знаю с какой стороны к этому подойти. А может посоветуете что-нибудь почитать для этого?

P.S. Пишу в Visual Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скилы можно прокачивать разные. Я рекомедую пойти на сайт олимпиадных задач (например этот http://acmp.ru/) и начать их решать. Там есть задачи от очень простых до очень сложных, так что проблем не будет. Прокачаются скилы работы с файлами, да и просто понимания задач.
Потом следует прокачать понимание сокетов.

Параллельно следует изучать ООП и резличные библиотеки (STL, Boost, Poco, ACE и другие).

Comment: Спасибо. Думаю олимпиадные задачи разовьют необходимую гибкость ума и прочее, этим и буду заниматься. Но как я уже говорил неплохо было бы прокачать скилл в написании программ решающих более приземленные повседневные задачи под винду. Но зачастую просто не имею представления с какой стороны к этому подойти.

Comment: как раз на олимпиадных задачах начального уровня хорошо прокачиваются элементарные навыки (чтение-запись файла, элементарные функции).

Comment: Чтение и запись файлов я уже прошел, если вы именно это имеете ввиду конечно. Подобных задачек достаточно порешали в универе и на паскале и на C++. С ООП я так же знаком, хотя думать согласно этой парадигме я ещё не привык.

Comment: Тогда stl и boost.